# Using Emac's SMIE to parse language with optional ; for statement termination

Tags: elisp, bnf, smie

I am using SMIE to parse a language that doesn't always require `;` to terminate a statement.
 If the end of a line is outside of a brace construct (`{}`,`()`,`[]`) and the last non-comment token was not an operator, then the `\n` acts as a statement terminator. Otherwise, if the end of the line is within a brace construct or the last token was an operator, then the `\n` acts as a continuation.

For example,

```
variable := 172 + 92; 

variable := 172 + 92

variable :=
    172 + 92;

variable :=
    172 + 92

variable := (172 +
    92)
```

are all valid statements. But,

```
variable 
    := 172 + 92
```

is not.

How can I encode this is the BNF grammar for SMIE (or any BNF for starters)? Or, is that not possible?

I understand how I might put this into the lexer and add `;` tokens as appropriate, but I would rather put it into the grammar if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't encode it in the BNF (because SMIE only accepts very weak BNFs which can't express that).  Look at how I did it for Octave mode: the tokenizer is made to return `";"` when it encounters a `\n` that is outside of a brace/bracket/paren (which you can check with `(zerop (car (syntax-ppss)))`).